# Pulling data from MySql into an array, then comparing the array's data to an existing variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an application I am working on, this was produced in Dreamweaver CS5. The code is quite rediculous, the person that made the site is not able to help so I am struggling through the code and trying to "simplify" some of it as I can. I am more of a beginner-intermediate with php. So it seems as if it could be not so difficult. Description of what the application "should" do: The customer table should display the data(which it does) and should show Prefix, Suffix, and State from the tables, however it has auto increment id's for the primary key and the text portion will not display, only the numbers. So my predecessor used if else statements to convert the number to data (you will see in the code how cumbersome this is). So here is my code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/customer.php'); ?><?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
  return $theValue;
}
}

$maxRows_DetailRS1 = 30;
$pageNum_DetailRS1 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_DetailRS1'])) {
$pageNum_DetailRS1 = $_GET['pageNum_DetailRS1'];
}
$startRow_DetailRS1 = $pageNum_DetailRS1 * $maxRows_DetailRS1;

$colname_DetailRS1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['recordID'])) {
  $colname_DetailRS1 = $_GET['recordID'];
   }
     mysql_select_db($database_customer, $customer);
     $query_DetailRS1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString          ($colname_DetailRS1, "int"));
  $query_limit_DetailRS1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_DetailRS1, $startRow_DetailRS1,         $maxRows_DetailRS1);
   $DetailRS1 = mysql_query($query_limit_DetailRS1, $customer) or die(mysql_error());
   $row_DetailRS1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($DetailRS1);

   if (isset($_GET['totalRows_DetailRS1'])) {
   $totalRows_DetailRS1 = $_GET['totalRows_DetailRS1'];
   } else {
    $all_DetailRS1 = mysql_query($query_DetailRS1);
    $totalRows_DetailRS1 = mysql_num_rows($all_DetailRS1);
 }
   $totalPages_DetailRS1 = ceil($totalRows_DetailRS1/$maxRows_DetailRS1)-1;

   $query = "SELECT id, state_abbr FROM state WHERE id =".$row_DetailRS1['state']."";

   $result = mysql_select_db($database_customer, $customer)
   or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<table width="41%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
  <td width="157">Id</td>
  <td width="469"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Prefix</td>
  <td><?php if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==1) {
    echo 'Mr.';}
    else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==2) {
        echo 'Mrs.'; }
        else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==3) {
            echo 'Ms.'; }
            else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==4) {
                echo 'Mr. &amp; Mrs.'; }
                else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==5) {
                    echo 'Dr.'; }
                    else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==6) {
                        echo 'Dr. &amp; Mrs.'; }
                        else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==7) {
                            echo 'Mr. &amp; Dr.'; }
                            else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==8) {
                                echo 'Drs.'; }
                                else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==9) {
                                    echo 'Hon.';}
                                    else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==10) {
                                        echo 'Hon. &amp; Mrs.'; }
                                        else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==11) {
                                            echo 'Mr. &amp; Hon.'; }
                                            else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==12) {
                                                echo 'Hons.'; }
                                                else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==13) {
                                                    echo 'Rev.'; }
                                                    else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==14) {
                                                        echo 'Rev. &amp; Mrs.'; }
                                                        else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==15) {
                                                            echo 'Atty.'; }
                                                            else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==16) {
                                                                echo 'Atty. &amp; Mrs.'; }
                                                                else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==17) {
                                                                    echo 'Mr. &amp; Atty.'; }
                                                                    else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==18) {
                                                                        echo 'Attys.'; }
                                                                        else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==19) {
                                                                            echo 'Sen.'; }
                                                                            else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==20) {
                                                                                echo 'Sen &amp; Mrs.'; }
                                                                                else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==21) {
                                                                                    echo 'Mrs. &amp; Sen.'; }
                                                                                    else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==22) {
                                                                                        echo 'Sens.'; }
                                                                                        else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==23) {
                                                                                            echo 'Rep.'; }
                                                                                            else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==24) {
                                                                                                echo 'Rep. &amp; Mrs.'; }
                                                                                                else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==25) {
                                                                                                    echo 'Mr. &amp; Rep.'; }
                                                                                                    else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==26) {
                                                                                                        echo 'Reps.'; }
                                                                                                        else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==27) {
                                                                                                            echo 'Mayor'; }
                                                                                                            else if($row_DetailRS1['prefix']==28) {
                                                                                                                echo 'Admin'; }; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Business Name</td>
   <td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['businessName']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['firstName']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Spouse Name</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['spouseName']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['lastName']; ?></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>Suffix</td>
<td><?php if($row_DetailRS1['suffix']==1) {
    echo 'Sr.';}
    else if($row_DetailRS1['suffix']==2) {
        echo 'Jr.'; }
        else if($row_DetailRS1['suffix']==3) {
            echo 'I'; }
            else if($row_DetailRS1['suffix']==4) {
                echo 'II' ; }
                else if($row_DetailRS1['suffix']==5) {
                    echo 'III'; }
                    else if($row_DetailRS1['suffix']==6) {
                        echo 'IV'; }
                        else if($row_DetailRS1['suffix']==7) {
                            echo 'V'; }
                            else if($row_DetailRS1['suffix']==8) {
                                echo 'Esq.'; }; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Address</td>
  <td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['address']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address Continued</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['addressCont']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['city']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State</td>
<td><?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($customer, $result)) {
    if($row_DetailRS1['state'] == $row) {
        echo '$row';}} ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Zip Code</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['zipCode']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone Number</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['phoneNum']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Alt. Phone Number</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['altPhoneNum']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>E-mail</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Board Member</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['boardMember']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Trustee</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['trustee']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Musician</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['musician']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Support Staff</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['supportStaff']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Active</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['active']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Deceased</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['deceased']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Comments</td>
<td><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['comments']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html><?php
mysql_free_result($DetailRS1); ?>
```

Comment: You could start by changing those horid elseif blocks to one liners that look into an array.

Answer (score 1):

I this code needs to be reworked. It's doing a lot of work in PHP that should be done in SQL. Do you have the ability to create new MySQL tables? If so, I would create 2 new tables (prefixes, suffixes) and I would pull the states query into the main query so you're not doing a separate query (extra DB hit).

As an example, here is how I'd do the prefixes table:

```
create table prefixes (
   prefix_id integer primary key,
   prefix_string varchar(20)
);

insert into prefixes (prefix_id, prefix_string) values (1, 'Mr.');
insert into prefixes (prefix_id, prefix_string) values (2, 'Mrs.');
... etc ...
```

Then the main query would be something like:

```
select c.*, p.prefix_string
  from customer c, prefixes p
  where c.prefix = p.prefix_id;
```

Then you'd be able to use `prefix_string` directly instead of the if/else mess. Do the same with suffixes and states.

If you don't have the ability to create tables, then I'd create PHP functions which convert the integer IDs to appropriate strings.

Comment: There are tables for prefix & suffix already, my tables are as follows: adtype, advertiser, chair, creditcardtype, customer, donor, donortype, events, paymenttype, prefix, sponsortype, state, subpackage, subscriber, suffix, user. The prefix & suffix tables are structured as follows: prefix- id(int(11)), suffixType(text); suffix-id(int(11)), suffixType(text); state-id(tinyint(4)), state(varchar(32)), state_abbr(varchar(8))

Answer (score 0):

If there's a problem you'll have to isolate it in this code to resolve it, it's a bit messy at the moment.  It looks like the **recordID** *GETVAR* is being used to lookup a user account in the database.  You should verify an id is getting passed in the request and that the user account is getting loaded from the database.  Then step through an find out what else might not be working, you can clean up the code as you go.  I've started out by cleaning up those spurious *else if* blocks.

**Prefix Block**

```
$aPrefixMap = array(
    1       => 'Mr.',
    2       => 'Mrs.',
    3       => 'Ms.',
    4       => 'Mr. &amp; Mrs.',
    5       => 'Dr.',
    6       => 'Dr. &amp; Mrs.',
    7       => 'Mr. &amp; Dr.',
    8       => 'Drs.',
    9       => 'Hon.',
    10      => 'Hon. &amp; Mrs.',
    11      => 'Mr. &amp; Hon.',
    12      => 'Hons.',
    13      => 'Rev.',
    14      => 'Rev. &amp; Mrs.',
    15      => 'Atty.',
    16      => 'Atty. &amp; Mrs.',
    17      => 'Mr. &amp; Atty.',
    18      => 'Attys.',
    19      => 'Sen.',
    20      => 'Sen &amp; Mrs.',
    21      => 'Mrs. &amp; Sen.',
    22      => 'Sens.',
    23      => 'Rep.',
    24      => 'Rep. &amp; Mrs.',
    25      => 'Mr. &amp; Rep.',
    26      => 'Reps.',
    27      => 'Mayor',
    28      => 'Admin'
);

$iPrefix = $row_DetailRS1['prefix'];
if(array_key_exists($iPrefix, $aPrefixMap))
    echo $aPrefixMap[$iPrefix];
```

**Suffix Block**

```
$aRowDetailMap = array(
    1 => 'Sr.',
    2 => 'Jr.',
    3 => 'I',
    4 => 'II',
    5 => 'III',
    6 => 'IV',
    7 => 'V',
    8 => 'Esq.'
);

$iDetailSuffix = $row_DetailRS1['suffix'];
if(array_key_exists($iDetailSuffix, $aRowDetailMap))
    echo $aRowDetailMap[$iDetailSuffix];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the id passes the customer record information on to this detail page, that part works, but when I am listing the prefix, suffix, and state that is where it goes arye. The code was out putting the primary key from of the item from the table, the tables are normalized and the redundancy is minimal, the notes that were left for me are very specific as to what the application is supposed to do but the code is very messy and hard to follow. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This worked great, is there a way to pull the array data from a table instead of listing out all the values? Maybe something like this:
    <?php $iState = array(); 
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, state_abbr FROM state"); 
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
      $array[] = $row[0]; 
      } 
    mysql_free_result($result); ?>

Comment: @MikeM yes, a query like that should get you the data into an array, but I think you want to change `$array[] = $row[0];` to `$array[$row[0]] = $row[1];` so you have an array like _$array[id] => state_abbr_.  Just be careful so the so the ids from the database correlate w/ the ids from the web page.

Comment: I tried this and I am getting lots of errors:
    `$query = "SELECT id, state_abbr FROM state";
    $r = mysql_query($query,$customer);
    $aStateMap = array(); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) { 
       $aStateMap[$row[0]] = $row[1]; 
    }`
Any idea why this is not working for me?

Comment: Hard to say, it looks mostly right to me.  Make sure **$customer** is valid when calling this code, and also inspect the value of **$row**, as well you can test **$r** before running the _while_ loop.